# What part of speech is “lower” in “lower-paid workers”?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> **Lower-paid** workers often cannot afford the high cost of living in the
> capital.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/high

What part of speech is “lower” in “lower-paid”?

Comment: It's a compound adjective with a past participle as head and an adjective as first component. See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It's a part of a compound word.

"Lower" isn't really a word in this context; it's a component in a larger compound word, "lower-paid". That's why it's hyphenized - it's saying that the two words "lower" and "paid" have been combined into a single word.

"Lower-paid" is itself an adjective, since it's describing "workers", which is a noun.

Comment: Yes, a compound adjective with a past participle as head and an adjective as first component.